# Python 2.7 Search Line if match pattern and replace string

Tags: python, regex

How can I read the file and find all lines match pattern start with \d+\s. And the replace the write space to , . Some of lines are contain English character. But some of line are Chinese. I guest the write space in chinese encoding is different with english?

Example (text.txt)

```
asdfasdf
1 abcd
2 asdfajklsd
3 asdfasdf
4 ...
asdfasdf
66 ...
aasdfasdf
99 ...
100 中文
101 中文
102 asdfga
103 中文
```

My Test Code:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as t:
    with open('newtext.txt', 'w') as nt:
            content = t.readlines()

            for line in content:
                    okline = re.compile('^[\d+]\s')
                          if okline:
                             ntext = re.sub('\s', ',', okline)
                             nt.write(ntext)
```

Comment: You want to replace all spaces with commas? Why not just use `str.replace`?

Comment: don't know why you check for the existence of `re.compile` object. It always return true, you mean `okline = re.match(r'\d+\s', line)` ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED
Before replace the spaces, I want to find out all the lines start with digit. As my sample file showing, there are some line are not start with digit. Those lines will not save to newtext.txt

Answer (score 1):

With single [***re.subn()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.subn) function:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as text, open('newtext.txt', 'w') as new_text:
    lines = text.read().splitlines()
    for l in lines:
        rpl = re.subn(r'^(\d+)\s+', '\\1,', l)
        if rpl[1]:
            new_text.write(rpl[0] + '\n')
```

---

The main advantage of this is that `re.subn` will return a tuple `(new_string, number_of_subs_made)` where `number_of_subs_made` is the crucial value pointing to the substitution made upon the needed matched line

Comment: Yes, it's work! But it only works on English character. In fact that, there are some lines are contain Chinese character. For lines contain Chinese character, it's fail. Sorry about that, I am a newbie on programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
# Reading lines from input file
with open('text.txt', 'r') as t:
    content = t.readlines()

# Opening file for writing
with open('newtext.txt', 'w') as nt:

    # For each line 
    for line in content:

        # We search for regular expression
        if re.search('^\d+\s', line):

           # If we found pattern inside line only then can continue
           # and substitute white spaces with commas and write to output file
           ntext = re.sub('\s', ',', line)
           nt.write(ntext)
```

There were multiple problems with your code, for starters `\d` is character class, basically `\d` is same as `[0-9]` so you don't need to put it inside square brackets. You can see [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Nj2uZ6/1). Also you were checking if compile object is True, since compile operation succeeds compile object will always be True.

Also, you should avoid nested `with` statements, more Pythonic way is to open files using `with`, read it, and then close it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why it output a 0 byte newtext.txt

Comment: Np. :) Can you accept my answer? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Enoch there was typo, did you copy `content = t.readlines()`?

Answer (score 0):

***Compact code***

```
import re

with open('esempio.txt', 'r') as original, open('newtext2.txt', 'w') as newtext:
    for l in original.read().split('\n'):
        if re.search("^\d+\s",l):
           newtext.write(re.sub('\s', ',', l)+'\n')
```